# Enable scroll bar only when overflow

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

In my code I use `overflow-y: scroll` to enable scroll bar and I set maximum height is 40px.
In chrome browser it works well and scroll bar is visible only when overflow occurs (that is text length is more than than 2 row).
But in firefox  web browser vertical scrollbar visible all time, my requirement is vertical scroll bar visible only when overflow occur or exceed height of 40px.

```
<div class="message-main-ok-text has-warning" style="max-height:40px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;">
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, change `scroll` to `auto`:

overflow-y:auto

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="message-main-ok-text has-warning" style="height: 110px;
  overflow: auto;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibheuismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>


</body>
</html>
```